# Basic file Handling in C++,EOF detection

Tags: c++, filestream, ifstream

I am reading an introductory book on C++.
In that there is an example program on opening a file.

The code is as follows...

```
    #include<iostream.h>
#include<fstream.h>
void main()
{
    ifstream fin;
    fin.open("country");
    while(fin)
    {
         ....
         .....
    }
}
```

Here is my doubt.
In the code the author says that,fin will evaluate to 0  if there are any errors in the file operation(including end-of-file condition).In this case how can an object be evaluated to an integer(i.e. 0. Or Some-non zero)?

Comment: See: http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool (and welcome to the wonderful world of overloaded operators).

Comment: Be aware that any errors or status will only be updated *after an I/O operation takes place*.  That means that using `fin >>` to read a value then may trigger EOF.

Comment: Note also that you might want to get a [newer/better book](http://stackoverflow.com/q/388242/253056) - `void main` is incorrect, as is the use of `<iostream.h>` and `<fstream.h>` (they have been obsolete for many years - it should just be `<iostream>` and `<fstream>`).

Comment: Throw that book away, it is out of date by some 18 years. C++ stopped using `<iostream.h>` in 1998.

Comment: Please suggest me some good books

Comment: [An absolute pleasure! I love suggesting good books.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/388242/the-definitive-c-book-guide-and-list) This isn't sarcasm. You have no idea how much time it saves in the long run.

Answer (score 2):

> In this case how can an object be evaluated to an integer?

By applying [operator bool](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/io/basic_ios/operator_bool).

Note that the

```
    while(fin)
```

is uncommon. Instead it should be used with an input operation. The test is then testing if the input operation is successful.  See for instance the linked example.

```
#include <iostream>
#include <sstream>

int main()
{
    std::istringstream s("1 2 3 error");
    int n;
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "(bool)s is " << (bool)s << '\n';
    while (s >> n) {  // Is read successful?
        std::cout << n << '\n';
    }
    std::cout << std::boolalpha << "(bool)s is " << (bool)s << '\n';
}
```